# Not able understand the error in java

Tags: java

I was trying to know what would happen if I have two classes with the main function.
I used the following code:

```
class A {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Hello,World!");
  }
}
class Hello {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Hello,World!");
  }
}
```

I compiled it using `javac First.java` (since no class is specified as public , I named the file as First.java); it got compiled without any error and i ran only the class A.Expecting the Hello class to run itself. DIDN'T HAPPEN(?),maybe the program ran out of scope.

So,

I tried compiling the following java code(I am a beginner) but i got the following error.
Code:

```
class Hello {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello,World!");                                                 
  }
}
class A {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello,World!");
    Hello.main();
  }
}
```

I compiled it through `javac First.java`and got the following error:

```
method main in class Hello cannot be applied to given types;

    Hello.main();
         ^
```

I wanted the program to run first the class A's main function and then class Hello's.
What's going wrong here?

Comment: Code formatting??? You need to call `Hello.main(args);` or pass any other string array. Read about passing arguments in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html).

Comment: Yes, *please* sort out your code. When you ask a question, you're presented with a preview of what it will look like. Ask yourself what *you* would want to see if you were going to answer the question. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: You need to pass a `String` array to `main()`.

Comment: Also, why would you expect the `Hello` class to run when you call `java A`. That's telling Java to run `A.main()`. And nothing else. Java programs aren't run from the beginning of a source file to its end.

Comment: Deeply Sorry about the code formatting, really I am .@jlordo @Jon

Comment: @millimoose: Look at `A.main` - it calls `Hello.main`.

Comment: I appreciate you experimenting, to learn more about it.

Comment: @JonSkeet I meant in the first example, which I thought "the program ran out of scope" was referring to.

Comment: @millimoose: I see what you mean.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the declaration of `Hello.main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Now you're trying to call it like this:

```
Hello.main();
```

What would you expect the value of `args` to be, within the method? You need to provide it with a value for `args`... and fortunately, you already *have* one, as you're within a method which uses `args` as a parameter, also of type `String[]`. So you should just be able to change your code to:

```
Hello.main(args);
```

Note that the two `args` parameters - one for `Hello.main` and one for `A.main` are entirely separate. We *happen* to use pass the value of one to the provide the initial value for the other, but we could easily have written:

```
Hello.main(null);
```

or

```
Hello.main(new String[] { "Some", "other", "strings" });
```

instead.

Comment: I witnessed @JonSkeet answering, for the first time!! I'm so happy :)

Comment: Me too, happy to be answering in the same question. Late in posting as I had to test it to be sure. This kind of chaining never occurred possible to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your second class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    MyOtherClass.main(args);
}
```